# Postgres CTE returns null, regexp_split_to_array also empty

Tags: postgresql

```
WITH cte as ( 
    SELECT partnerlist as a FROM support.members WHERE id = 'BB36' 
) 

SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY('BB36,'||(SELECT a FROM cte), ',')
```

The cte returns null, no rows.

Why wouldn't the regexp_split_to_array return `[BB36]`?

It is used in a `where` clause like this in my full query:

```
AND u.id = any(regexp_split_to_array('BB36,'||(SELECT a FROM cte), ','))
```

Comment: Concatenating with null returns null regardless of the other values being concatenated. Perhaps, instead: `'BB36,'||COALESCE((SELECT a FROM cte), '')` But... even that seems strange. You may end up concatenating your `bb36` with an empty string, or a result set depending on what's returned and neither of those scenarios seems like something you would want.

Comment: Yeah, using COALESCE didn't work, either. Any way to check for null?

Comment: If I use `NULLIF()` it still returns null or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the CTE to this made it work:

```
WITH cte as ( 
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN partnerlist IS NULL OR urgpartnerslistori = '' THEN
            'XX99'
        ELSE 
            partnerlist 
        END as a 
    FROM support.members WHERE id = 'BB36' 
)
```